# Animate the loading of html content into a div

Tags: jquery

I have a click function which grabs the contents of one div and loads it into another. I'd like to add a simple fade to that loading. Here's what I have so far:

```
$("ul.portfolio li a").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var content = $(this).next('.clickContent').html();
$("#container").html(content).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

It's not working. The content just loads. Any idea how to get this to animate??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to hide the div first:

```
$("ul.portfolio li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).next('.clickContent').html();
    $("#container").hide().html(content).fadeIn('slow'); // added .hide()
});
```

Comment: I love it when it's something simple! Thanks!